# Laravel Xdebug warning

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I am getting a warning when debugging my Laravel application in PhpStorm

(The stack is PHP7.1 + Laravel, starting the server with `php artisan serve`)

The thing is that it does debug without any troubles, it stops at the breakpoint and I can execute or jump inside functions without any troubles. But after I press `resume program execution` the script finishes correctly, however a warning is thrown `Debug session was finished without being paused`.

Comment: And what is the question exactly? This looks more like a bug report that should be on the JetBrains forums.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206315469-Debug-session-was-finished-without-being-paused

Comment: "Debug session was finished without being paused" means that some script that was meant to be debugged run without stopping at any breakpoint. It could be completely different script or hit for another resource (e.g. missing favicon.ico or alike). It might also be some breakpoint that is set in "bad place" (not every line is good for setting it). I suggest to check your browser's Dev Tools | Network Tab to see what other URLs might get hit + configure xdebug logging -- it may give you hint what script gets execute etc.

Comment: @RonS seems I have the same. Can you post this as question and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206315469-Debug-session-was-finished-without-being-paused

This thread seems to be the replica of your problem.

Cheers!